# Getting port from developer tools

Tags: networking, browser, port

Is it possible to get the port number a page is connected to via developer tools tab in browsers?

I looked under the "Network" tab but it did not seem to help.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm presuming you mean the port on the server. This is decided by the protocol:

http: port 80

https: port 443

Servers can infact serve pages on any port they wish, can you can specify to connect to a different port, by appending it to the domain name, like so:

http://portquiz.net:8080/

Comment: Duh how silly of me, I forgot they were standard.  Thank you.